# Developing Fourier series of step-wise functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let a step-wise function be defined as:

\begin{equation}
    f(\xi):=\sum_{i=0}^n \eta_i\chi_{A_i}(\xi)
\end{equation}

where $n\geq 0$,  $\eta_i$ are real numbers, $A_{i}$=$[\xi_i, \xi_{i+1}]$ , $i = 1,2,..., n-1$ are intervals, and $\chi_{A}$ is the indicator function of $A$:

\begin{equation}
   \chi_{A}=\begin{cases}
   1 \ \ \ if \ \  \xi\in A_i \\0 \ \ \ if \ \  \xi \notin A_i
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Let furthermore  $[a,b]=A_{i}=[\xi_i, \xi_{i+1}]$

we can then develop the Fourier series be defined by

\begin{equation}
   f(t):=\alpha_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k \cos kt +\beta_k\sin kt
\end{equation}

where we can develop the Fourier integrals of the coefficients for the step wise intervals:

where the coefficients are solved by the Fourier integrals:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cc}
     \alpha_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{i=0}^n\eta_i\int_{\xi_i}^{\xi_{i+1}}  \text{d}t=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{i=0}^n\eta_i\big(\xi_{i+1}-\xi_{i}\big)\\
     \alpha_k=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{i=0}^n\eta_i\int_{\xi_i}^{\xi_{i+1}}  \cos kt \text{d}t=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{i=0}^n\eta_i\bigg( \frac{\sin (k\xi_{i+1})}{k}-\frac{\sin (k\xi_{i})}{k}\bigg)  \\
     \beta_k=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{i=0}^n\eta_i\int_{\xi_i}^{\xi_{i+1}}  \sin kt \text{d}t=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{i=0}^n\eta_i\bigg( \frac{\cos (k\xi_{i})}{k}-\frac{\cos (k\xi_{i+1})}{k}\bigg) 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Since we are covering the interval $[a,b]$ composed of multiple steps we also have:

\begin{equation}
   \bigcup_{j=1}^nA_j=[a,b],
\end{equation}

We then get the Fourier series given by the formula, where we put $t=\xi$ for convenience:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
        f(\xi)=\bigcup_{j=1}^n\bigg\{\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{i=0}^n\eta_i\big(\xi_{i+1}-\xi_{i}\big)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\bigg[\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{i=0}^n\eta_i\bigg( \frac{\sin (k\xi_{i+1})}{k}-\frac{\sin (k\xi_{i})}{k}\bigg)\bigg]  \cos k\xi + \\ \bigg[\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{i=0}^n\eta_i\bigg( \frac{\cos (k\xi_{i})}{k}-\frac{\cos (k\xi_{i+1})}{k}\bigg) \bigg]\sin k\xi\bigg\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

But somewhat, there is an error in the Fourier integrals, and in the last equation.

I cannot find the error, does anyone have an idea of what I did wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Be specific, what error do you see?

Comment: Hi Paul, I am unsure about the union sign in front of the integral, and I am unsure about the integrand in the large brackets inside the SUM

Comment: What is the domain of f? Is it the interval  [a, b] which is partitioned into n sub intervals? If you then repeat this to create a periodic function it will have period $b -a$ and fundamental frequency $\frac{2 \pi}{b-a}$. Your series looks like it has period $2 \pi$ and period 1.

Comment: @Paul the domain of f is [a,b], and is not $[-\pi,\pi]$. PS I found an error in the integrals and corrected it, but the whole thing is still not good.

Comment: Is your function equivalent to the sum of [boxcar functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxcar_function) $f(\xi):=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \eta_i\, (\theta(\xi-\xi_{i+1})-\theta(\xi-\xi_i))$ where $\theta(\xi)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)? You say the domain of $f$ is $[a,b]$, but you also say $[a,b]=A_{i}=[\xi_i, \xi_{i+1}]$, so the period of your Fourier series is not clear to me. What is the period of your Fourier series?

Comment: Presumably the period of your Fourier series can be expressed as $T=B-A$ where $A\le \xi_i\le B$ for all $0\le i\le n+1$. Your formulas seem to suggest that $T=B-A=2 \pi$.

Comment: The period of the fourier series is $-\pi,\pi$, but the entire domain of step-intervals is $[a,b]$